# Frida Call System.load() to load library

Tags: javascript, emulation, frida

I'm trying to call System.load to load the current application's library using Frida, but it didn't succeed.

My code:

```js
let System = Java.use("java.lang.System");
System.load(str);
```

When executing I always get the error:

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.ClassLoader java.lang.Class.getClassLoader()' on a null object reference
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/env.js:124)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1233)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:639)
    at apply (native)
    at value (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1137)
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:606)
    at <anonymous> (C:\SuperTools\Apk\Frida scripts\hook.js:116)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:205)
    at <anonymous> (C:\SuperTools\Apk\Frida scripts\hook.js:137)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/core.js:51)
```

Anyway I can fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Your code snippet is a bit too short to say what is going wrong. Based on the error message I assume you are calling it at the wrong time, so may be you forgot to encapsulate your Frida code correctly: `Java.perform(() => { your code }`? Do you start the app (early instrumentation) or do you attach to an existing process? Which line of your code is `hook.js:116`?

Comment: you can just do `Java.perform(() => {})` in the cli and then continue as normal